# How to rename Stack Overflow for Teams Team

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have a Stack Overflow for Teams team that I'd like to rename (our project name has shifted, but the team has remained the same).

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be an admin on the team to be able to rename it. Go to your team then go to the admin settings. Under the `Appearance` tab you can go down to `Name & URL` and from there you can change the name and/or the URL of the team.

Comment: Where are the admin settings?

Comment: The left bar or `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<team name>/admin/settings` soon to be the new domain of `stackoverflowteams.com` but not yet

Comment: In order to change the name, hit Enter after typing in a new name.